# Can we create a column of character varying(MAX) with PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, sqldatatypes

I am unable to set the max size of particular column in PostgreSQL with `MAX` keyword. Is there any keyword like `MAX`. If not how can we create the column with the maximum size?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you want to created an "unbounded" `varchar` column just use `varchar` without a length restriction.

[From the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html)

> If character varying is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size

So you can use:

```
create table foo
( 
  unlimited  varchar
);
```

Another alternative is to use `text`:

```
create table foo
( 
  unlimited text
);
```

More details about character data types are in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

Answer (score 10):

You should use `TEXT` data type for this use-case IMO.

[image]
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-character.html